# Codeigniter URI issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using a CI system for my web app. Until yesterday everything was working fine, but suddenly I am getting 403 Error when I hit this URL: https://riidl.org/fablab/dell/123/rajdhiravani@gmail.com

but if I hit this URL :
https://riidl.org/fablab/dell/123/rajdhiravani@gmail.in

it works!

Also if I try https://riidl.org/fablab/dell/123/rajdhiravani.com@gmail.com

it works!

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Fablab extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->library('session');
         $this->load->model('fablab_model');
         $this->load->model('login_model');
 }
 public function dell()
 {
     $booking_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $email = $this->uri->segment(4);
  echo $booking_id;
  echo $email;
  exit;
 }
  
 }
```

and my .htaccess file is :

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

DirectoryIndex index.php

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: So firstly - you could call your function like this: `dell($booking_id,$email)` and CI will handle it for you. Could you also output your routes. file?

Comment: `<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';  
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['startupschoolindia'] = 'programs/startup_school_india';
$route['startupschool'] = 'programs/startup_school_india';
`

Answer (score 0):

The characters permitted by CodeIgniter to be part of a URL are specified in the file `application/config/config.php`, specifically `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`.

The default values specified by CodeIgniter does not permit the @ character to be part of the URL.

If you want to allow `@` character, edit the `config.php` file and add the `@` character to the value of `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`.

Comment: But his question says that @gmail.in is working - it doesn't appear to be the @ sign

Comment: Yeah @ sign is working. I have already included that in $config['permitted_uri_chars']. The problem is .com

Comment: @RAJDHIRAVANI I think you are better of thinking of other ways to pass the email to the function for example using sessions.

Comment: @RobertOdoch I am generating that link from an email. User gets an email with that link and user clicks on the link to complete the task. URI is the only way to pass the parameters.

Comment: @RAJDHIRAVANI record the user's email in a database table and generate a code associated with the email and pass it in the link instead. When users return with the link, you can check the email associated with the code in the URL. BTW your site is nice.

Comment: Yeah! I passed /0 at the end of the URL.  It works. But still, don't know what caused that issue.  Anyways thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is treating the .com as a domain extension and hence not allowing direct access as there is no index.html or index.php file in the root directory.
The web server will always handle the request first before passing it on to codeigniter

Comment: I have included index.html as well as index.php in the root directory. Still, the problem exists.

Comment: I meant to say your server is treating https://riidl.org/fablab/dell/123/rajdhiravani@gmail.com as a domain name and expects an index.html file in the root directory of "https://riidl.org/fablab/dell/123/rajdhiravani@gmail.com" and hence it throws a 403 error. Your actual domain is https://riidl.org/ but the server is treating https://riidl.org/fablab/dell/123/rajdhiravani@gmail.com as a .com domain and expects an index.html file in the root directory.

Comment: Also if I try https://riidl.org/fablab/dell/123/rajdhiravani.com@gmail.com

it works!

Comment: Let me know how to let know server to treat it differently ?